# Refresh page on back browser button

Tags: javascript, jquery

is possible reload taget page with back button of browser?

Example: I want reset all data/cache of page when user press back button on browser.

Comment: this might help you find an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your questions is very poorly written, I believe it is more important that you get the answer you're looking for.

Do the following:

1. Add event listener to the window/document(in your case, keydown)
2. Get the ascii code of backspace(0x08 or 8 in decimal)
3. Prevent the default functionality of keydown
4. Refresh the page if it is backspace

Here it is in code.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e)
{
    if( e.keyCode == '8' )
    {
        e.preventDefault();  // prevent backspace from going to browser
                          // history
        // add reload code
        location.reload();
    }
}, false);
```

Link to event listener

[MDN Event Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: is possible apply "location.reload();" to browser back button?

Comment: I hardly think so, since Javascript only modifies what is inside of the window and not the browser itself